# Setting up Auto Mail Forwarding using Outlook Mail Rest API

Tags: rest, api, outlook, office365

Is it possible to set up Auto Mail Forwarding using Outlook Mail Rest API for Outlook 365 mailbox?
I need a way to do using a .Net console app.
Looking at the API documentation it only mentions how to forward a mail message, but not auto forwarding.

Comment: It seems that this is no such a  feature as you requested. Also, what is your automatic condition? Whether you need to add a rule?

Comment: Looking for a way to programmatically (via a .Net app) to enable/setup Mail Forwarding for an Outlook 365 mail account.  Basically, a way to do this with a custom app instead of using the Outlook 365 web client app.